# How to fix : Sql logic error sqlite3 in Clion?

Tags: c, sqlite, cmake, clion

I'm trying to link sqlite3 library to CMakeList in Clion using the following code:

```
find_package(SQLite3)
target_link_libraries(IIWProject SQLite::SQLite3)
```

Library has been loaded but when i Run the code, Clion shows the following error:

```
SQL logic error
```

The database has been loaded but when `sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL)` was called return `SQL logic error`

```
void get_db(sqlite3 **db){
    int rc;
    if ((rc = sqlite3_open("db_project.db", db)) != SQLITE_OK){
        //fprintf(stderr, "Failed to open DB.\n");
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to open DB: %s\n\r", sqlite3_errstr(rc));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
}

int clear_table(sqlite3 *db){
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt;
    int rc;
    char* query = "DELETE FROM resources";
    if ((rc=sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query, -1, &stmt, NULL)) != SQLITE_OK){
        fprintf(stderr,"Failed to prepare statement: %s\n\r", sqlite3_errstr(rc));
        return 1;
    }
    if ((rc = sqlite3_step(stmt)) != SQLITE_DONE){
        fprintf(stderr,"Delete failed: %s\n\r", sqlite3_errstr(rc));
        return 1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I try to fix it?

EDIT:
If I compile, without Clion manually, with `gcc -lsqlite3`,it work

Comment: Does that table exist in the database you opened? (`sqlite3_errmsg()` can give more relevant messages than just the generic error code, btw)

Comment: The table exist because if i open the same project with a makefile from linux console it works without any errors. I can't provide more detailed error messages because I don't know how to retrieve them in Clion.

Comment: Are you sure you're opening the exact same database file from the command line and from your IDE? -- And you'd use `sqlite3_errmsg()` instead of `sqlite3_errstr()` like you are now. Refer to the documentation for usage.)

Comment: Yes I'm sure the database is the same . The error matched with `sqlite3_errmsg()` is `Signal: SIGSEGV (Segmentation fault)`

Comment: I... don't know how you managed to get `sqlite3_errmsg()` to segfault but that's impressive. Did you read the documentation to see what its argument is? Did you get any compiler warnings however you did try to use it?

Comment: I'm sorry but I edited the error function without change the argument of `sqlite3_errmsg()`.  The error was ` no such table: resources` but if I inspect the database with database manager from Clion, the table exist.

Answer (score 0):

Now that we've established that the table doesn't exist when you run your program though your IDE...

The current working directory when you run your program through a command line is different than the current working directory your IDE runs it in. Since you're using a relative path to the database file, this means you're using a different one depending on how you run your program. Only one of the databases actually has the table(s) you're trying to use.

Some solutions:

- Use an absolute path to the database.
- Configure your IDE to use the same working directory as when you're running your program through a command line.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I solved by adding `set(CMAKE_RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR})` in CMakeList.txt